# Java and converting displayed value into local time zone and daylight savings

Tags: java

I know this is an oft asked type of question, and I've been looking around the web for solutions, but to no avail. The problem is that we're fetching a date value from the database and want to display it in a PDF in local time. The raw formatted value is "2022/05/24 15:18:10" and using Costa Rica as an example client time zone (we're in LA), we'd want this "2022/05/24 16:18:10". However, we're getting this: "2022/05/24 17:18:10".

One of the odd things I'm seeing when I run the code below is that it seems that our server time zone is PST, according to Java, but is actually PDT.

```
    creationDate from db=Tue May 24 15:18:10 PDT 2022
    Desired creationDate output=2022/05/24 16:18:10
    cal.getTimeZone.getDisplayName()=Pacific Standard Time
    formatted creationDate=2022/05/24 17:18:10
```

So one question is: why are we seeing PST instead of PDT and the second question is how do I fix this?

Example code:

```
    public static void main(
      String[] args)
    {
      final String DATE_TIME_PATTERN = "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss";
      final String LA_TIMEZONE_ID = "America/Los_Angeles";
      DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_TIME_PATTERN);
      TimeZone serverTimeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone(LA_TIMEZONE_ID);
      Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(/* serverTimeZone */); // works same with or without param
      TimeZone clientTimeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("CST"); // Costa Rica = Central Standard Time
      Date creationDate;
      
      df.setTimeZone(clientTimeZone);
  
      // Values as fetched from database.
      cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 24);
      cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.MAY);
      cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2022);
      cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 15);
      cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 18);
      cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 10);
      creationDate = cal.getTime();
  
      System.out.println("creationDate from db=" + creationDate.toString());
      System.out.println("Desired creationDate output=2022/05/24 16:18:10");
      System.out.println("cal.getTimeZone.getDisplayName()=" + cal.getTimeZone().getDisplayName());
      System.out.println("formatted creationDate=" + df.format(creationDate));
    }
```

Comment: So doing just a little bit hacking, Costa Rica seems to be -6, but "Central Standard Time" seems to -5 .  While Costa Rica is listed as "Central Standard Time", it actually has it's own timezone (`America/Costa_Rica`), I mean "America/*" has 167 individual timezones and "US/*" has 12. From what (little) I understand "Central Standard Time" is somewhat meaningless in your context (don't quote me on that, time zones confuse my to hell)

Comment: What database? What exactly is the table column’s data type? How are you retrieving from the database, what SQL, what JDBC code? Into what Java data type are you receiving from the database? Why are you still using the terrible legacy date-time classes when hundreds of Answers have advised using only *java.time* classes?

Comment: @BasilBourque Oracle DATE column using JPA\Hibernate. Using java.util.Date because it's a legacy app.

Comment: Those details need to go into your Question as edits, not Comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, after a bit of hacking and googling, it would appear (at least to me), that "Central Standard Time" isn't what you want to use (nor should you use it generally).

From [time-and-date/Central Standard Time (CST)](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/cst)

> **Caution: This is NOT the current local time in most locations in that time zone**
> **North America**: Only some locations are currently on CST because most places in this time zone are currently on summer time / daylight saving time and are observing CDT.

And then add in [time-and-date/Time Zone in Costa Rica](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/costa-rica)

> Costa Rica observes Central Standard Time all year. There are no Daylight Saving Time clock changes.

That's not confusing at all .  So, as I "understand" it, CST is normally -6 hours and CDT is -5 hours, but Costa Rica is always -6 hours.

So, based on the observations of your code, `CST` seems to be having the day light savings value applied to it, regardless of what you do.

So, what to do about it?  Well, the simple answer is, don't use it, in fact, stop using the `java.util.Date` and related APIs altogether and instead, make use of the replacement `java.time` APIS and the `America/Costa_Rica` time zone directly, for example...

```
final String DATE_TIME_PATTERN = "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss";
final String LA_TIMEZONE_ID = "America/Los_Angeles";
final String dateStringValue = "2022/05/24 15:18:10";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse(dateStringValue, formatter);

ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of(LA_TIMEZONE_ID);
ZonedDateTime zdt = ldt.atZone(zoneId);

System.out.println("     Local = " + ldt);
System.out.println("       zdt = " + zdt);
System.out.println("Costa_Rica = " + zdt.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("America/Costa_Rica")));
System.out.println("US/Central = " + zdt.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("US/Central")));
```

which prints...

```
     Local = 2022-05-24T15:18:10
       zdt = 2022-05-24T15:18:10-07:00[America/Los_Angeles]
Costa_Rica = 2022-05-24T16:18:10-06:00[America/Costa_Rica]
US/Central = 2022-05-24T17:18:10-05:00[US/Central]
```

This is probably also a good (and over due) reason to dump the old `java.util.Date` and related classes and update to the `java.time` APIs, see the [date/time trail](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html) for more details

[Handling Daylight Savings Time in Java](https://www.baeldung.com/java-daylight-savings) might also be worth a read

Comment: Would love to go to java.time, but this is a legacy app and at best we could probably only have new code use java.time.

Comment: @GaryKephart This could be the straw that breaks the back 

Comment: Could be, but knowing my manager, it won't be.